# Determing exit point of application. C++/Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working on a big app (ns2) and somewhere someone put an exit(1) in there without any debug or print statements and it is being executed. I don't want to have to manually check every file that calls exit to figure out why the program is exiting. Is is possible to determine where the program exited? This is running on Linux and coded in C++. Is it possible to do something like this in gdb?

Comment: The breakpoint on exit is probably the best approach (or Greg's exit replacement) but I did want to mention "find , -name '*.c' -exec grep 'exit{' {} \;" as another option than scanning the files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.  Put a breakpoint at the start of exit(3).  When it breaks, look at the stack.

Second choice, run it under truss(1) (I'm pretty sure there's a Linux version of truss.)

Or [strace(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

#### Update

In fact, I ran across another method in another question:  [here's a link](http://ndevilla.free.fr/etrace/).

Comment: Unless they were cruel enough to call _exit() or _Exit() instead of exit()...probably best to trap all three.  truss/strace won't identify where the system call is called from.

Comment: No, but I usually find that the sequence from a truss, strace, or ltrace (*another* option) gives me enough of a clue to find it.  The find/grep I put in a comment would work if all else fails.

Answer (score 3):

If you supply your own implementation of `exit()`, then that one will be used in preference to the one in the library. Build that, load it in the debugger, put a breakpoint on your `exit()`, run the program, and see where it came from.

Or as [Charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764555/determing-exit-point-of-application-c-linux/764561#764561) says, just put a breakpoint on the library `exit()`. Use the above method if you want to run some other specific bit of code instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have access to the source code I would simply search for the call to exit and analyze the code. Then you can most likely also fix it by replacing the exit with something more appropriate.

If all your code is in the directory *src* the a

```
grep -r exit src
```

should find all occurences of the word exit

If you do not have access to the code go with the suggestion(s) of Charlie.